# PHP exec() from URL?

Tags: php, url, exec

I have a php file with an *exec()* function that executes some unix commands when I do this: **php file.php** on terminal, but now I need to do the same from URL on the browser, that is: **localhost/file.php**

So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: 1. Show your current code. 2. will this file ever be on a public facing server?

Comment: Not safe at all.. but if you'd really want to do that, what is your exact problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. The problem was that the files which I used in the commands inside exec() were outside of the */var/www/html* directory and apache was complaining about permissions and after I had to give them permissions with the *chown* command.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a web server. It's a huge topic so it can't be covered here.

However. If you just want to run a simple PHP server, try

```
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

From the root directory of your PHP application. It should be accessible in your browser by going to localhost:8000. Or to make it accessible on any interface:

```
$ php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Note that this only work for newer versions of PHP (>=5.4).